# URL Mapping on a wordpress redesign

Tags: wordpress, dns

I have recently redesigned a website on wordpress. The redesign is in a subfolder of the domain. When I flipped the new website live by following this tutorial 'Using a pre-existing subdirectory install' - (http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) everything worked as planned.

However, I am still getting the old site when I navigate to the site using www in the url.

Answer (score 0):

This is a likely problem with your hosting setup. Sounds like you don't have your "A" records setup quite right. Check out this GoDaddy support article for an example. It'll be similar across all hosts.

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/680/managing-dns-for-your-domain-names
Click on "To Add a Record" and read that. Some hosts will require you to have a "@" and a "www" record to make the site direct to the same place with or without the www.

Also remember that it can take up to any hour for records to get updated.

If all else fails, give your host a call!